# Solr searching with /terms

Tags: php, solr, character-encoding, schema, tomcat6

I have a PHP application that uses a SOLR database.
The problem appeared when I am doing a /terms request ([terms doc](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent))

So the parts of the document that interest us are

```
poi: "BistriÅ£a",
...
text: [
"ddt",
"Numeric",
"/14/Gagaga 2/11/Economics/17/datenow",
"/20/Daniel_same/11/Economics/17/datenow",
"0/Gagaga 2",
"1/Gagaga 2/Economics",
"2/Gagaga 2/Economics/datenow",
"0/Daniel_same",
"1/Daniel_same/Economics",
"2/Daniel_same/Economics/datenow",
"ppla",
"seat of a first-order administrative division",
"/19/Daniel_same/1071/Plurinational State of Bolivia/2269/Cuba/2272/BistriÅ£a",
"0/Daniel_same",
"1/Daniel_same/Plurinational State of Bolivia",
"2/Daniel_same/Plurinational State of Bolivia/Cuba",
"3/Daniel_same/Plurinational State of Bolivia/Cuba/BistriÅ£a",
"0/Undefined_activity",
"Year",
"0/1999",
"0/1999",
"Measured",
"",
"utf8"
],
```

And the request is

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/terms
?wt=json
&indent=true
&terms.sort=count
&terms.mincount=1
&terms.limit=10
&terms.regex.flag=case_insensitive
&terms.regex=.*bi.*
&terms.fl=text
```

The response is

```
{
    responseHeader: {
        status: 0,
        QTime: 4
    },
    terms: {
        text: [
            "bistriå",
            16
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem with the result is that the resulted text is truncated. I was expecting "BistriÅ£a" which is an UTF-8 encoding of a city [Bistrița](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bistri%C8%9Ba).
But the result seems to be truncated at the special character.

The weird thing is if I do the request with the field name "poi" instead of "text", I get a correct response

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/terms
?wt=json
&indent=true
&terms.sort=count
&terms.mincount=1
&terms.limit=10
&terms.regex.flag=case_insensitive
&terms.regex=.*bi.*
&terms.fl=poi

{
    responseHeader: {
        status: 0,
        QTime: 4
    },
    terms: {
        text: [
            "BistriÅ£a",
            16
        ]
    }
}
```

So the word is not truncated.

The big difference between the 2 fields is the type. *Poi* has a **string** type and *text* has a **text_general** type. The text_general type is defined in the schema like this

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I can provide more details if asked. Not sure what I can add now and not bloat the question too much.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to consider using the [AsciiFoldingFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory) in your `text_general` field to appropriately handle the special character. Additionally, please refer to the [Language 
Analysis](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis) support provided by Solr that may be of use to you.